# Zend Framework 2 nothing happens after an interaction with the button in the from

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am working on an webapp using zend framework 2 and I would like to set up a form in order to provide a possibility to edit a certain entity. I have been following a tutorial form the zend framework's home page and there I have seen how it actually works. I have successfuly implemented a controller, form, fieldset and a phtml page. My form should have two buttons, first which submits the form (save) and the second one which cancels the operation (cancel). Both of them are now inside the form. Save is an input element of type submit and the other is a button element of type button. As you can see I have set the action to the button but when I click on it nothing happens (no redirection). Could somebody expain me where am I making a mistake?

```
<?php
$form->prepare();
$sourceFieldSet = $form->get('source');

$title = $sourceFieldSet->get('title');
$title->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$title->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Geben Sie Ihrer Quelle einen möglichst aussagekräftigen Titel');
$title->setLabel('Titel der Quelle');

//....

$save = $form->get('submit');
$save->setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary');

?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="headingBlock">
        <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->title); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row mainPageBlock">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="centerForm">
                <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>

                <?php echo $this->formHidden($sourceFieldSet->get('familyTreeId')->setValue($familyTreeId)); ?>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <?= $this->formRow($title); ?>
                </div>

                //other rows
                //....

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <?= $this->formRow($form->get('cancel')->setAttribute('action', $this->url('familyTreeMaintenance', array( 'action' => 'sources', 'id' => $familyTreeId, 'title' => 'Quellen' )))); ?>
                    <?= $this->formRow($save); ?>
                </div>

                <? echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe It would be also useful for you to see how my form looks like and how I have defined the button there.

```
<?php

namespace Sources\Form;

class SourceForm extends Form {

public function __construct($name = null) {

    parent::__construct('sourceForm');

    $this
        ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodHydrator())
        ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter())
    ;

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->add(array(
        //'name' => 'source',
        'type' => 'Sources\Form\SourceFieldset',
        'options' => array(
            'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'Speichern',
            'id' => 'submit',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'button',
        'name' => 'cancel',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Abbrechen',
        ),

    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'delete',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'Löschen',
            'id' => 'submit',
        ),
    ));
}

}
```

Comment: you have forgot to set action attribute. you can put this before form opentag  $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')));
 $form->prepare();

Comment: What do you mean by "you have forgot to set action attribute"? for what? I have set the action for the cancel button. You can see it in the last 'div' in the form above.

Comment: if you view html source (using firebug) you will notice <form> tag has no action attribute you need to set if's not set and regarding cancel it looks okay and it should work or you can do like this:- <a href="<?php echo $this->url('category', array('action' => 'index')); ?>" class="Cancel">Cancel</a>

Comment: Thx! Action attribute in the form was not necessary. Although it is not set, the save action was working. The problem was the cancel action and this second proposal with <a href=""/> solved it.

Comment: Can you please answer this question and mark your answer? You will get points for that.